# Credentials within parallel foreach statement in RunBook

Tags: azure-automation

I'm trying to recreate a set of virtual machines (based on existing OS disks) from a PowerShell workflow runbook. The issue I bump into is that I need to create the security context within the parallel execution block, and this always fails. I get the message to run "Login-AzureRmAccount", which I already try to do using

```
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection 
Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint
```

I have an existing script the runbook is inspired from, which is only different in the fact that it uses PowerShell Jobs to parallelize, and it uses a profile saved on disk to set the security context in the job script block (which runs in a separate process).

So basically, I would help a lot if someone could confirm that this is possible from a parallel execution block, and if so, how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like my runbook setup may have been wrong. I was starting from a PS runbook, which in turn was calling into a PS workflow runbook. Seems like things were going wrong there. I restarted the whole setup, with a workflow runbook at the root, calling into a child runbook containing the parallel loop execution. Things are running fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use different connections in the foreach loop iterations? I don't think Add-AzureRmAccount is designed for concurrent execution in the same runbook... If you need all foreach loop iterations to work with the same connection, the obvious solution would be to perform Add-AzureRmAccount before entering the loop. However, if you actually need different connections, consider other ways to parallelize execution: for example, spawn separate Automation jobs.

Comment: I could maybe use a runbook per virtual machine that needs to get set up, but first I'm trying to run one runbook to do all the work. I was under the impression that a foreach with -parallel option does not inherit the connection from the upper context, which is why I try to connect for each item in the collection.